# PHP - How can i update multiple values using checkboxes?

Tags: php, html, checkbox

i have one HTML table with values from a specific database table.

Every html table is generated by a foreach loop that i created to get all the table information, and they are organized like this:

[image: First image]

The first checkbox is to eliminate the table row, is working fine, the second checkbox is to update.

I will try to explain what i'm trying to do:

Lets imagine that you are an user, and you want to update some values from the database, you will need to check all the checkboxes from the rows that you want to update, and click at a button called "edit".

After you click edit, appears all the informations from those rows that you selected.

I'm trying to get the values from those selected rows, but i dont know how to do it

I already have the code in HTML, that i inserted inside the foreach loop

```
<td><input style='width: 50px;' class='edit' value='Edit' type='submit' name='edit[]' /></td>

  <td><input style='width: 50px;' type='checkbox' name='editcheck[]' value=".$key['id']." /></td>
```

I'm using a kind of MVC structure with my own rules, i cant put the query on the view. i want to create a function inside the model and call this function on view.

How can i do that?

I just want some example, using Foreach please, thanks.

Comment: i am still interested what *MVC structure with my own rules* means

Comment: I guess a custom MVC framework..

Comment: it is however still not clear what you are struggeling with. Your HTML seems okay'ish. You haven't provided any foreach code that fails or described what errors you get or what part of foreach you didn't understand despite the available online tutorials and documentation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i am kind of shooting into the blue here but ..

You already iterate over *all* those database rows to present the lines that look like your screenshot, giving the user the option toi select those lines that she wants to edit/delete.

So i assume you know how to get data from your database using queries.

Now, when presenting your lines, your checkboxes get the id's of the rows as values and those values will be delivered to your processing script via `post`.

So in your processing script, if you var_dump your post data (`$_POST`), you should be able to see how clicking certain checkboxes affects the data you receive. So it might look like this:

```
$_POST = array (
  'editcheck' = array(
  3, 6, 9, 12
  )
);
```

So the rows with the id 3, 6, 9 and 12 should be edited.

Now you can iterate over your `$_POST` variable, using foreach to read each row from your database or you simply use the given array in your query. Example:

```
$query = "SELECT * FROM yourTable WHERE id IN ( " . implode (',', $_POST['editcheck']) ." )";
```

Read up on [implode](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.implode.php) if you do not know this function. And read up on [MySQL IN Clause](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/mysql/mysql-in-clause.htm) if you use MySQL or read up on your Database Query language and find something similar. Or, if you use some kind of ORM/DBAL tool like Propel or Doctrine, find the equivalent there.

Now, if you found a solution where one query gives you all the rows from editcheck, you can surely iterate over that result since it is not at all different from iterating over the rows the way you did it before.

I hope this helped.
Still, i recommend reading some very basic PHP Tutorials since this is very, very, very basic stuff.